# Separate Reference list based on multiple bib files

Tags: bibtex, citing, moderncv, cv

I have read through out many post concerning the use of multiple .bib files in order to use `\nocite` and multiple bib files, into a CV. The goal is my cv to have a different sector per bib files.

I saw that most suggestions pointed out the moderncv.tex package, thus I used the packages suggestion to adapt their commands and into my CV.

I use two different files a journal.bib and a conf.bib (exported from Mendeley).

the MWE for the two .bib files are 
for the journal.bib

```
@article{journal,
author = {Smith, A},
journal = {A journal},
title = {{A journal}},
year = {2016}
}
```

for the conf.bib

```
@inproceedings{Conf,
author = {Smith, A},
booktitle = {Conference 1},
title = {{Conference title}},
year = {2016}
}
```

The .tex file is MWE is

```
\documentclass{article} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.2in,top=0.3in,right=0.2in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{journal}
\bibliography{journal} 

\renewcommand{\refname}{Conferences}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{Conf}
\bibliography{conf} 

\end{document}
```

When i use only one the list in the document is fine, although when I move on and change into the second bib file the produced file does not correpond to the result I want.
I get this 
[image]

Although what I want is something like that (it has been hand written it, not automated)
[image]

I have read and tried also other option such as `\multibib`, `\biblatex` etc. but perhaps I am missing something, or not understand it correctly.
Any help would be great, thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

`Biblatex` allows you to do this in a very simple way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{journal.bib} 
\addbibresource{conf.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title={Journal Articles}, type=article, resetnumbers=true]

\printbibliography[title={Conference Papers}, type=inproceedings, resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

For each bib file you want to use you have to use  one `\addbibresource` (it does no matter what entry type they contains). Then, to print all references of type `article` you use the `type=article` of `\printbibliography` (similarly for the other entry types).

To create the pdf file, run `(pdf)latex` once, then `biber` and  the `(pdf)latex` again.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to compile, but it produces nothing,

Comment: do you compile with `biber`?

Comment: Yes I added through the configuration biber twice before pdflatex, but no go

Comment: it is pdflatex, biber, pdflatex

Comment: Yes I have assigned PDFlatex-biber-PDFLatex to build

Comment: what does the logs tell you?

Comment: Log says biblatex.sty "no backend" specified, that type "article" not found, type "inproceeding" not found, and that the bibliography (bbl is empty). I checked the bib files and they are as the one I posted, odd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41605/discussion-between-guido-and-george).

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this where separation is by source bibliography file? I'd like to separate my preprints from my other publications, but the "type" as auto-translated by zotero doesn't disambiguate the two, and I'd rather not monkey with the internal structure of the bib file, since I generally let zotero generate them for me.

Comment: there is the "keyword" parameter for filtering as well, so you might be able to munge keywords in as filter criteria e.g. `\printbibliography[title={Preprints}, keyword={preprint}, resetnumbers=true]`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code for using different references from different files in Latex:

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs04} % your referencing style

% with two reference files of ref1.bib and ref2.bib:
\bibliography{ref1.bib, ref2.bib}
```